# Leaflet custom marker doesn't work on multiple points

Tags: views, hooks, 10

I am using Geofield field with Leaflet module.
I need to customize the marker and I'm having a problem with content types that have more than one point on the map.

While for ctypes that have only one dot the marker is replaced correctly, for cypes that have multiple dots or a dot and a dash the marker always returns to the default one.

Has anyone had a similar problem and know how to fix it?